# Coffeescript one liner for creating hashmap with variable key

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Is it possible to do the following in one line in coffeescript?

```
obj = {}
obj[key] = value
```

I tried:

```
obj = { "#{key}": value }
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Nop AFAIK. But [LiveScript](http://livescript.net/) does it with that exact syntax. http://codepen.io/elclanrs/pen/gevai

Comment: You could do `(obj = {})[key] = val` but it's not exactly better? Why does it need to be on one line?

Comment: @phenomnomnominal I often do something like this:
```options = {}
options[someVar] = someValue
someFunction(options)```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone that finds this question in the future, as of CoffeeScript 1.9.1 interpolated object literal keys are once again supported!

The syntax looks like this:

```
myObject =
  a: 1
  "#{ 1 + 2 }": 3
```

See https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/commit/76c076db555c9ac7c325c3b285cd74644a9bf0d2

Answer (score 4):

```
(obj = {})[key] = value
```

will compile to

```
var obj;

(obj = {})[key] = value;
```

This is normal javascript. The only benefit you get from coffeescript is that you don't have to pre-declare `var s` because it does it for you.

Answer (score 4):

[It was removed from the language](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1731#issuecomment-2210542)

> Sorry for being tardy -- if I remember correctly, it was because some
>   of our other language features depend on having the key known at
>   compile time. For example, method overrides and super calls in
>   executable class bodies. We want to know the name of the key so that a
>   proper super call can be constructed.
>
> Also, it makes it so that you have to closure-wrap objects when used
>   as expressions (the common case) whenever you have a dynamic key.
>
> Finally, there's already a good syntax for dynamic keys in JavaScript
>   which is explicit about what you're doing: `obj[key] = value.`
>
> There's something nice about having the `{key: value, key: value}` form
>   be restricted to "pure" identifiers as keys.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how complex your key is you can always use a variable name matching your key and use it to define an object, like this:

```
myKey = "Some Value"
obj = {myKey}
```

Which will compile to:

```
var myKey, obj;

myKey = "Some Value";

obj = {
  myKey: myKey
};
```

So what you end up with is something *close* to what you seek, but that requires your keys to be valid variable names.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [underscore](http://underscorejs.org), you can use the `_.object` function, which is the inverse of the `_.pairs` function.

```
_.pairs({a: 1, b: 'hello'})
//=> [['a', 1], ['b', 'hello']]

_.object([['a', 1], ['b', 'hello']])
//=> {a: 1, b: 'hello'}
```

So, assuming `myKey = 'superkey'` and `myValue = 100` you could use:

```
var obj = _.object([[myKey, myValue]]);
//=> obj = {superkey: 100}
```